# Use global memory for (big) local/private temp. data structure efficiently in OpenCL

Tags: qt, memory-management, opencl

I'm writing an algorithm in OpenCL which needs a data structure temporarily (during execution) only. This is going to be big enough to exceed most device's local or private memory. So I have to use the global memory for this data.

I read about the different memory types in OpenCL and I know that accessing global memory randomly is really slow. In my case, every work group accesses different addresses in the global memory, so in other words, I use the global memory as a kind of local memory.

So what I ask myself is now, if the device "knows" that I don't read data written by another work group / item, can memory access be speeded up? What exactly does `__constant` effect in terms of memory access mechanism? Could I misuse this or a similar keyword? Or is there even a keyword / method for my problem I overlooked?

Another thing is: The memory for this data structure only has to be allocated in the device's memory; I do not need to access (not even initialize) it in the host. Is there a more efficient way to do this than send an uninitialized array to the device? I use QtOpenCL which lets me pass a host-initialized vector of primitives which is converted (host-)internally to a buffer and sent to the device on kernel invocation. So I'm looking for a QtOpenCL-way to do this. AFAIK, only local memory can be allocated from within kernel. (I get errors when defining an array as `__global`.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to improve access to global memory in your case (though coalesced memory access and prefetching could nearly completely hide latency). However, you can try to declare your variables local, and let the compiler decide which of them should be moved to global memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the constant buffer size is usually rather small (e.g. 64kB on my GTX 580 and this size is shared accross all work-groups similary as the 48kB local memory), I think that using the constant buffer wouldn't be a solution. I would suggest to look at images - in optimization examples these are often used - these are cached for 2D spacial locality, the access needn't to be coalesced.

Btw, I have somewhere saw that disabling L1 cache with some compiler option on NVidia can result in slightly better performance with often random access to global memory.

For the second question: I think that if you don't pass any of the `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` or `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` flags the memory on host is not allocated and therefore nothing can be copied to the device.